# Bookmark a POST request

Tags: software-recommendation, safari, google-chrome, web-browsing, http

Certain online shops I use don't easily allow you to bookmark an Order Status page.
That's because they use a [POST request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_request) to access that info. So, the order number is not encoded in the URL. Which means that I can't bookmark the page (a bookmark just leads to the form to enter the order number).

So, **I'm looking for a way to bookmark a POST request** so that I can easily view my order status page without having to enter the order number again.
I'd love to hear about a browser extension (or built-in functionality), a dedicated app, or any other ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the page with the form locally on your hard drive.

You will then need to modify the source code to replace the textbox with a hidden field that has the same name and id as the text box and with a value of what you are searching for.   eg

```
<input type="textbox" id="searchtext" name="searchtext" />
```

and replace it with

```
<input type="hidden" id="searchtext" name="searchtext" value="343434" />
```

Replace "343434" with whatever you are normally putting into the text box.

Save this file.  And book mark it.   When you visit the page, you should just need to click the submit button and it will send the form along.

High chance that this won't work first time.  But let me know and I can guide you though any other changes that need to happen.  If its a publicly accesible site, let me know the url and I can help you out quicker.

Comment: That's excellent! A very elegant solution; I wish I could upvote multiple times.

Comment: Unless the browser does it for you (I believe Firefox may and Safari doesn't), you may need to add a `BASE` element to the document's `HEAD` in case the form target is a relative URL: `<head> ... <base href="` *original document URL* `"> ... </head>`. Also, a refinement on this strategy would be to add JavaScript so that the form automatically submits when you load the page.

Comment: @Kevin When you save the page with Chrome (and Safari, I believe) it takes care of relative URLs. As for the JS: I'm contemplating writing an extension for it :)